# How to mute MediaPlayer in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How to mute MediaPlayer in android

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This code worked for me,

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

for **Mute**

```
mp.setVolume(0,0);
```

& **Unmute** or **full volume**

```
mp.setVolume(1,1);
```

Comment: the two digits mean L and R channel, so the unmute one should be mp.setvolume(1,1);

Comment: I know this is a long time after, but I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to set the volume. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: you should initialize first and while setting volume should cross check that not null

Comment: this will only mute one audio file. What if I have multiple audio files and I want to globally turn  sound on/off  from any activity?

Comment: For multiple audio files you are using multiple instance of media player so you have to mute all instance .

Answer (score 13):

```
 AudioManager   mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    int current_volume =mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //If you want to player is mute ,then set_volume variable is zero.Otherwise you may supply some value.
    int set_volume=0;
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,set_volume, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

You might want to fade out/in the sound instead of setting it immediately to full (1.0f) or zero (0.0f) volume.

It's a little bit tricky, because you need an async task to keep your app responsive:

mpMain is my MediaPlayer instance to play the looping background music.
I also care about it in OnPause() and OnResume().

Method playBackgroundMusic is used to turn the music on, fadeOutBackgroundMusic turns music off, but by fading out volume for 0.5 seconds (10*50, see while and Thread.sleep).

My base-volume is 0.8f, you might want to make that a parameter of the async task or use a static global variable.

```
public void playBackgroundMusic( Boolean isOn ){
  if(isOn){
    // prevent conflics with async fade-out task
    if(mtask_fadeout_music!=null){
      mtask_fadeout_music.cancel(true);
      mtask_fadeout_music=null;
    }
    if(mpMain==null){
      mpMain = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.zin___piano_2_140bpm_32158);
      mpMain.setLooping(true);
      mpMain.setVolume(0.8f,0.8f);
      mpMain.start();                         
    }
  }
  else{
    if(mtask_fadeout_music==null){
      fadeOutBackgroundMusic();
    }
  }
}

public void fadeOutBackgroundMusic(){
  mtask_fadeout_music = (FadeOutMusic)new FadeOutMusic( ).execute( );
}


//
//  background processing ... fade out music stream
//
public class FadeOutMusic extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    float level = 0.8f;
    int i = 1;

    while(i<50){
        i++;
        if(mpMain != null){
          level=level*0.9f;
          mpMain.setVolume(level, level);         
        }
        try {
          Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "dummy";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute( String dummy ) {
    if(mpMain != null){
      mpMain.setVolume(0,0);         
      mpMain.release();
      mpMain = null;  
    }
    if(mtask_fadeout_music!=null){
      mtask_fadeout_music = null;
    }
  }       

  @Override
  public void onCancelled() {
    if(mpMain != null){
      mpMain.setVolume(0,0);         
      mpMain.release();
      mpMain = null;  
    }
    if(mtask_fadeout_music!=null){
      mtask_fadeout_music = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`AudioManger.setStreamMute` is deprecated. 
use below alternative code.

```
AudioManager am = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Change the stream to your stream of choice. 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
       am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
    } else {
       am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use below methods to use for mute/unmute or to check whether the audio player is in mute state or not

```
/**
 * To Mute or Un-mute using Audio Manager
 */
private fun updateMuteState(mute: Boolean) {
    activity?.let {
        getAudioManager(it).adjustStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            if (mute) -100 else 100,
            0
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Return true -> audio player is in mute state, false otherwise
 */
private fun isMute(): Boolean {
    activity?.let {
        getAudioManager(it).getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC).let { volume ->
            return volume == 0
        }
    }
    return false
}

/**
 * To Get the Audio Manager
 */
private fun getAudioManager(context: Context) =
    context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

It will mute Complete media volume to mute

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AudioManager am = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Request audio focus.
am.requestAudioFocus(listener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for un-mute even in silent mode

```
 MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alarmUri);
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.7f,0.7f);
 mMediaPlayer.prepare();
 mMediaPlayer.start();
```