# Mute a playing video by VideoView in Android Application

Tags: android, video

I want to mute a playing Video by VideoView in my Android Application.
I couldn't find any method to do so in VideoView Class.
Any idea how to do this?

I have found a method  "setVolume"   in MediaPlayer Class,  But I am unable to find any working code to play video by MediaPlayer class.
So I believe I can set volume 0 by this method.

Therefore I am looking for any working code to play video using MediaPlayer Class  or  how to control volume using VideoView   Class.

Below is the code for playing video using VideoView , which I am using.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    String _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/video5.mp4";

    videoView.setVideoPath(_path);

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();


}
```

Comment: Try using AudioManager suggested in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573667/how-to-mute-mediaplayer-in-android).

Comment: Hi yorkw,
I want to play video in Mute mode.
SO how to play video with AudioManager?

Comment: Using VideoView play video while using AudioManager control volume.

Comment: Thanks.  Its working.
Btw one more question, now I want to play other music with this muted Video.
Then how it is possible?

Comment: Actually When I set volume to 0 by AudioManager for video.
Its set the volume 0 for my other song which I am playing.
Any idea to do this.
i.e.   Play video (mute)  with other song in background with my Android application.

Comment: Vishal, see my answer below!

Comment: Why not just mute device's volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this using MediaPlayer class.
I have used setVolume  function of MediaPlayer class to set the volume to 0.
also I have realised that dont use AudioManager class, because using AudioManager if a set volume to 0, then it set volume to 0 for all the instance of MediaPlayer and  VideoView.  But if you will use setVolume() method of MediaPlayer then it will just Mute the volume of that instance only.

Also set volume to 0 is bot easy using VideoView because VideoView is a wrapper over MediaPlayer class and just allow to access few function of MediaPlayer.
Also I have read on some blog that though you can reference MediaPlayer instance using VideoView instances, but its very complex and its not recommended to do so.
Hope this would be helpful to other new readers how try to do similar things.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to get access to the `MediaPlayer` of a `VideoView` you have to call `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` and `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`, then you can call `MediaPlayer.setVolume(0f, 0f);` function to set the volume to 0.

Do this:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

  VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);
  String _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/video5.mp4";

  videoView.setVideoPath(_path);
  videoView.setOnPreparedListener(PreparedListener);

  videoView.requestFocus();

  //Dont start your video here
  //videoView.start();


}

MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener PreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {
         try {
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                }
                m.setVolume(0f, 0f);
                m.setLooping(false);
                m.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
     }
 };
```

Comment: Sometimes working, sometimes not. @RajiAC - found any reliable solution?

Answer (score 29):

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sometimes working, sometimes not. My guess is if videoView is visible by the time mp.setVolume is called, mute happens. Otherwise, no action takes place. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Obviously it happens at the time of loading of videoView

Comment: What if i want to mute during the playing of video programmatically?