# How to show volume seek bar on video view in android?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, seekbar, android-videoview

I have added a video view in android.I am able to display the video & it is all working fine.But i don't see any volume control.I want show volume control.please tell me how can i show the volume control on video view in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [Seekbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435275/mute-a-playing-video-by-videoview-in-android-application) to your layout and add a OnSeekBarChangeListener to it. In the listeners callback implement the logic, see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435275/mute-a-playing-video-by-videoview-in-android-application) for details.