# VideoView black background in Fragment

Tags: android

I adding VideoView in fragment but only I get black background nothing more I tried with two codes but both doesn't work can you help me?

PS I don't need play, stop button and anything other just to show the video Here is the code that I add will be good if I can mute the audio of the video and replay

Code 1

```
package com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises;

import android.media.session.MediaController;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.VideoView;   
import java.net.URL;    

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BenchFragment extends Fragment {
    private VideoView MyVideoView;

    public BenchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench, container, false);
        MyVideoView = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bench);
        MyVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        MyVideoView.start();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench, container, false);
    }    
}
```

Code2

```
package com.hristijan.aleksandar.gymworkout.myapplication;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView MyVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoViewId);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bench);
        MyVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        MyVideoView.start();

    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.BenchFragment">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this to play,replay and identify the error

```
private void startVideo() {
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.crop;
//  Log.e(TAG,Uri.parse(path) + " ");
    video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    video_view.start();
    video_view.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int i, int i1) {
            Log.e(TAG,String.format("Error: What: %d, Extra: %d",i,i1));
            return false;
        }
    });
    video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

If the video doesn't play it should log error in LogCat. You can identify what kind of error using this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html)

> About Muting the Audio

You can refer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12435275/2299040) basically you just need to get the media player object when the content is ready then you can mute the audio by setting  **`m.setVolume(0f, 0f);`**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting *videoView.start()* inside **videoView.setOnPreparedListener()** as:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
    @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
        videoView.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that Code 1 and Code 2 can work

First, make sure your video format is [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#video-formats)

Then, make sure your video file `bench` stored in  `...app\src\main\res\raw` (And your file name should be `bench` not `bench.xxx`)

On the other hand, in Code 2 something is wrong:

<s>MyVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoViewId);</s>

should be

```
MyVideoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
```

in order to find a VideoView by correct `Id`

Comment: Good;) try dig deep on Android, I saw you got many questions about your Exercise app.

Comment: Yeah thanks again can you tell me how can i put Ads in the background? because they make my ui to lag too much