# Kill app processes after exit?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, service

I have the following code which plays some audio after some time in a service. The issue is, after exiting the app, the media player continues to run; I want to stop the audio from playing after the app has has been exited or closed.

[image]

By the way, ten and three were declared at the top:

MediaPlayer ten;
   MediaPlayer three;

**Does some piece of code run every time an app is closed?** If so, I could call stopService() from that piece of code.

I would really appreciate any feedback (positive or negative)! Thank you so much for all of your help, let me know if you need any more code.

```
{Rich}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStop` you can `mute player` 
and

`onResume` you can `play music player`.

`OnDestroy` you can stop your service

```
stopService(new Intent(YourService));
```

For reference mute and unmute player

[How to mute MediaPlayer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573667/how-to-mute-mediaplayer-in-android)

Comment: Which gets called when one leaves by pressing the home button or back button?

Comment: Also, how do I stop it if there is an incoming call or something?

Comment: By pressing home button activity will go in backgroud so onStop will call.But on pressing back button activity will kill so onDestroy will call

Comment: For block call plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android

Comment: No, I don't want to block the call. I want to stop my service when incoming call comes. The problem is, music still plays in background when someone calls me while i'm using my app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android have a lifecycle that run the onCreate, onPause, onStop and onDestory. When you exit the app and wish to stop the player, you might want to do something in the onStop.

You can look at the lifecycle at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks John! Is there a way that I can mute it in the on pause? How do I mute my android app until the user comes back? Thanks so much, I will mark you best answer(+15 rep) and like your post (+5 rep) once I get this figured out!

Comment: Well, you can use the setVolume function in the Mediaplayer API and set it to setVolume(0,0), look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float) for reference

Comment: That will change the entire devices volume, which users may dislike. How can I mute **only** my app?

Comment: If that is the case, why not just use .pause() ?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you were saying. I set the mediaplayer volume, but am getting a null pointer exception. Any idea why?

Comment: ten.setVolume(0, 0);
three.setVolume(0, 0);

Comment: public static void mute(){
        ten.setVolume(0, 0);
        three.setVolume(0, 0);
    }

    public static void unMute(){
        ten.setVolume(1, 1);
        three.setVolume(1, 1);
    }

Comment: TwentySeconds.unMute(); and             TwentySeconds.mute();

Comment: your ten and three variable should be null that cause that to happen, it depends when you call those. Do a trace in debug mode to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one activity that is *always* the task root and *only* the task root, overriding `onBackPressed` in that activity is probably the best way to tell if the app is "exiting" as far as the user is concerned.  You would not want to kill the process when the activity is merely sent to the background.

Comment: What do you suggest doing for multiple activities

Comment: @Rich If you have multiple activities, you haven't exited the app.

Comment: The thing is, the user is always switching between activities. If they decide to press the home button, I want to shut all processes. How can I do that? I don't have control over **where** the user will exit the app, but **wherever** he/she does, I want to exit all processes.

Comment: @Rich "If they decide to press the home button, I want to shut all processes." -  That's a great way to piss off your users.  If the user presses home, the app should remain running.  (Or at least it should appear that way to the user.)

Comment: I agree, the thing is, it would piss them off even more if there were random sounds running every few seconds while they are trying to use another app. Is there a way I can mute my app until they come back? I will mark you best answer and like your post as soon as I get this to work. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Rich If you want the sound to stop when the activity is not visible, mute it in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.  See the link in John's answer.

Comment: @Rich That calls for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Thing you needed to check is when app goes in background and when app goes in background stop your service. For that you needed use

```
ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
```

You can find more info about from here [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Also an example which will help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13809991/5059946)